Spring boot Mqtt is connecting and receiving msgs but after a while it stops receiving messages without giving any error
This is my connection config class to mqtt producer.
package uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageProducer;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.MqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.support.DefaultPahoMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.security.core.parameters.P;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.config.properties.MqttProperties;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.dto.sensorReading.RxSensorReadingDto;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.entity.SensorReadingLog;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.exception.CustomException;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.logging.LogService;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.service.SensorReadingLogService;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.service.SensorReadingsService;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import static uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.util.ErrorUtil.getStacktrace;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@Profile({"dev", "prod"})
public class MqttConfig {
    private final MqttProperties mqttProperties = new MqttProperties();
    private MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(mqttProperties.getClientId(), mqttClientFactory(),
                        mqttProperties.getTopic());
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(2);
        adapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        this.adapter = adapter;
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[]{mqttProperties.getUrl()});
        options.setUserName(mqttProperties.getUsername());
        options.setPassword(mqttProperties.getPassword().toCharArray());
        options.setCleanSession(false);
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler(ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                                  LogService logService,
                                  SensorReadingsService sensorReadingsService,
                                  SensorReadingLogService sensorReadingLogService
    ) {
        return message -> {
            try {
                String payload = (String) message.getPayload();
                Map<String, Object> data = objectMapper.readValue(payload, new TypeReference<>() {
                });
                String time = data.get("time").toString().split("\\+")[0];
                byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode((String) data.get("data"));
                String hexData = new String(Hex.encode(decoded));
                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time).plusHours(5L);
                Long fcnt = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(data.get("fCnt")));
                String dr = (String.valueOf(data.get("dr")));

                Map<String, String> deviceInfo = (Map<String, String>) data.get("deviceInfo");
                Map<String, String> txInfo = (Map<String, String>) data.get("txInfo");
                List<Map<String, String>> rxInfo = (List<Map<String, String>>) data.get("rxInfo");
                String devEui = deviceInfo.get("devEui").toUpperCase();
                RxSensorReadingDto dto = RxSensorReadingDto.builder()
                        .devEui(devEui)
                        .hexData(hexData)
                        .dateTime(dateTime)
                        .fcnt(fcnt)
                        .build();
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sensorReadingsService.saveData(dto));

                Map<String, String> rx = rxInfo.get(0);
                SensorReadingLog sensorReadingLog = SensorReadingLog.builder()
                        .jsonObject(payload)
                        .fcnt(fcnt)
                        .hex(hexData)
                        .devEui(devEui)
                        .dr(dr)
                        .freq(String.valueOf(txInfo.get("frequency")))
                        .snr(String.valueOf(rx.get("snr")))
                        .rssi(String.valueOf(rx.get("rssi")))
                        .read_timestamp(dateTime)
                        .gatewayId(String.valueOf(rx.get("gatewayId")))
                        .port(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(data.get("fPort"))))
                        .build();
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        sensorReadingLogService.save(sensorReadingLog);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logService.logException(null, getStacktrace(e), e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            } catch (CustomException | JsonProcessingException e) {
                logService.logException(null, getStacktrace(e), e.getMessage());
            }
        };
    }
}


I also set up listeners for connection failed event
package uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.events;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.event.MqttConnectionFailedEvent;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.event.MqttSubscribedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.logging.LogService;
import uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.service.notification.TelegramNotificationService;

import static uz.soliddata.uzgasmonitoring.constant.enums.LogType.MQTT;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MqttEventListeners {
    private final TelegramNotificationService telegramNotificationService;

    private final LogService logService;

    @EventListener
    public void connectionFailed(MqttConnectionFailedEvent event) {
        logService.logInternal("connection failed: " + event.getCause(), MQTT, "");
        telegramNotificationService.SendMessage("connection failed: " + event.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void successfullySubscribed(MqttSubscribedEvent event) {
        logService.logInternal("connection opened: " + event.getMessage(), MQTT, "");
        telegramNotificationService.SendMessage("successfully connected: " + event.getMessage());
    }

}


I am working with 4000 iot devices they send gas pressure information on 15 minute interval. It was working fine till yesterday but suddenly its I am receiving any message if I use postman to receive message it works fine without any interruptions. If i restart application It receives messages for 15-30 minutes then suddenly stops what can be problem ?
I also saw some forums where they talk about thread locking on these type of problem but I do not get it. How can I solve this application already in production ?
